Can Sitecore 10.4 containerized applications be hosted on OpenShift?
I'm working on deploying a Sitecore 10.4 containerized application, and I want to know if it is feasible to host it on OpenShift.
Any guidance, best practices, or references , mainly limitations for deploying Sitecore 10.4 on OpenShift would be greatly appreciated!
